# implementing getFilter(). into custom ArrayAdapter with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

i´m newbie in android programming and try to implement getFilter() into my custom ArrayAdapter an filter the List by Name.
I have not found any example that matches with my adapter.

Can someone help me with an example please (with my code), thx!!!

Maybe there is another possibility to filter the List?

java code:

```
public class c_DTArtikel_allforsearch extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView ListViewLayout;
private EditText search;
private String[] Name;
private String[] Number;
private int[] ImagesID;
private ArrayList<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_lv_search);


    Resources res = getResources();

    String[] saugname = res.getStringArray(R.array.SauglanzeName);
    String[] pumpmname = res.getStringArray(R.array.PumpMName);

    String[] saugnummer = res.getStringArray(R.array.SauglanzeNumber);
    String[] pumpmnummer = res.getStringArray(R.array.PumpMNummer);

    TypedArray saugimg = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.SauglanzeImg);
    TypedArray pumpmimg = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.PumpeMImg);

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    name.addAll(Arrays.asList(saugname));
    name.addAll(Arrays.asList(pumpmname));
    Name = name.toArray(new String[saugname.length+pumpmname.length]);

    ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<String>();
    number.addAll(Arrays.asList(saugnummer));
    number.addAll(Arrays.asList(pumpmnummer));
    Number = number.toArray(new String[saugnummer.length+pumpmnummer.length]);

    ArrayList<Integer> imgInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int nr = -1;
    while ( ++nr < saugimg.length() )
        imgInts.add (saugimg.getResourceId(nr, 0));
    nr = -1;
    while ( ++nr < pumpmimg.length() )
        imgInts.add (pumpmimg.getResourceId(nr, 0));
        ImagesID = new int[imgInts.size()];
    for (int i=0; i < imgInts.size(); i++)
    {
        ImagesID[i] = ((Integer) imgInts.get(i)).intValue();
    }


    Search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextSearch);

    ListViewLayout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLayoutSearch);

    final TIAdapter adapter = new TIAdapter(articleList, this);
    ListViewLayout.setAdapter(adapter);
    ListViewLayout.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    //has been missing
        for (int i = 0; i < Name.length; i++)
    {
        Article a = new Article(Name[i], Number[i], ImagesID[i]);
        // Binds all strings into an array
        articleList.add(a);
    }

    // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
   search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("Text ["+s+"] - Start ["+start+"] - Before ["+before+"] - Count ["+count+"]");
            if (count < before) {
                // We're deleting char so we need to reset the adapter data
                adapter.resetData();
            }

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                     int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
```

Class Article

```
public class Article {

    public String Name;
    public String Number;
    public int ImagesID;

    public Article(String Name, String Number, int ImagesID) {

        this.Name = Name;
        this.Number = Number;
        this.ImagesID = ImagesID;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
        return Number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.Name = Number;
    }
    public int getImgID() {
        return ImagesID;
    }
    public void setImgID(int imgID) {
        this.ImagesID = ImagesID;
    }
}
```

Class custom adapter:

```
        class TIAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> implements Filterable {
    private List<Article> articleList;
    private Context context;
    private Filter articleFilter;
    private List<Article> origArticleList;

    TIAdapter(List<Article> articleList, Context ctx) {
        super (ctx, R.layout.layout_text_image, articleList);
        this.articleList = articleList;
        this.context = ctx;
        this.origArticleList = articleList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return articleList.size();
    }

    public Article getItem(int position) {
        return articleList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return articleList.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ArticleHolder holder = new ArticleHolder();


        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_text_image, null);

            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            holder.textViewArtikel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewArtikel);
            holder.textViewArtikelNummer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewArtikelNummer);
            holder.imageViewArtikel = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewArtikel);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {

            holder = (ArticleHolder) v.getTag();
            holder.imageViewArtikel = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewArtikel);
            DecodeTask dt1 = (DecodeTask)holder.imageViewArtikel.getTag(R.id.imageViewArtikel);
            if(dt1 != null)
                dt1.cancel(true);
        }

        final Article n = articleList.get(position);

        holder.imageViewArtikel.setImageBitmap(null);
        DecodeTask dt2 = new DecodeTask(getContext(), holder.imageViewArtikel,  n.getImgID());
        dt2.execute();

        holder.textViewArtikel.setText(n.getName());
        holder.textViewArtikelNummer.setText(n.getNumber());
        holder.imageViewArtikel.setTag(n.getImgID(), dt2);
        return v;
    }

    public void resetData() {
        articleList = origArticleList;
    }

    private class ArticleHolder {
        TextView textViewArtikel;
        TextView textViewArtikelNummer;
        ImageView imageViewArtikel;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (articleFilter == null)
            articleFilter = new ArticleFilter();

        return articleFilter;
    }



    private class ArticleFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = origArticleList;
                results.count = origArticleList.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<Article> nArticleList = new ArrayList<Article>();

                for (Article a : articleList) {
                    if (a.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                        nArticleList.add(a);
                }

                results.values = nArticleList;
                results.count = nArticleList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                articleList = (List<Article>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }
}

    }
}
```

here is the code from old getView();

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ImageView imageView = null;

        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_text_image, parent, false);
            imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewArtikel);
        }
        else {
            imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewArtikel);
            DecodeTask dt1 = (DecodeTask)imageView.getTag(R.id.imageViewArtikel);
            if(dt1 != null)
                dt1.cancel(true);
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        DecodeTask dt2 = new DecodeTask(getContext(), imageView, ImagesID[position]);
        dt2.execute();

        TextView textViewArtikel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewArtikel);
        TextView textViewArtikelNummer = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewArtikelNummer);

        imageView.setTag(R.id.imageViewArtikel, dt2);
        textViewArtikel.setText(Name[position]);
        textViewArtikelNummer.setText(Number[position]);
        return row;
    }
```

decode Task

```
public class DecodeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    Context mContext;
    ImageView v;
    int resId;

    public DecodeTask(Context context, ImageView iv, int res_id) {
        mContext = context;
        v = iv;
        resId = res_id;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return decodeBitmapFromResource(resId, 300, 300);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        v.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
    private Bitmap decodeBitmapFromResource(int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), resId, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), resId, options);
        return bmp;
    }

}
```

Error logcat:

```
05-03 10:56:43.922  28792-28792/com.kreussler.krapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.kreussler.krapp.c_DTArtikel_allforsearch$TIAdapter.getView(c_DTArtikel_allforsearch.java:286)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Sergej as I said before, you first have to adapt your adapters constructor to accept one items array instead of three arrays. Only if that is ok you can implement a getFilter() method. Meanwhile you will have been reading this forum and have found todays post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339478/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-search-not-working  There you see how the items array is called <Users> and how the class Users is declared. You have to do that also. Make your adapter first work (without filtering) in this way. You have to adapt a lot of code in the adapter but it is easy.

Comment: Hi, i almost updated the code. one thing what i can't solve is my class Articles. I get error "incompatible types". my arrays are Strind[], String[], Int[] and 
required for the class is String, String, Int. can i convert this? if yes how? the code is updated

Comment: it works, see "has been missing" above. now i can filter. but they are filtering from the first letter. example if i put in "a" the list show only words that beginning with "a". also i need to implement asynctask for the pictures because the list is very slow.

Comment: Well you did that quick! You forgot to adapt:  final TIAdapter adapter = new TIAdapter(this, Name, Number, ImagesID); Will deep into your code later...

Comment: You mean sentences that start with an a. Well that is because in your Filter you use startsWith("a"). Add someting to the condition or change it.

Comment: Please place the "has been missing" code at the right place in the source. That is less confusing.

Comment: updated! now it's function with the filtering. do you have any example to set asynctask in this kind of adapter to load pictures in background?

Comment: Let me see the new filtering.... Adapt the code i mean.

Comment: You had a decodeTask. You just can use that again. Place that task in the source here please.

Comment: i'm not able to implement my decodeTask, could you help me? code is adapted.

Comment: It would have been nicer if you gave the reasen why not. And what you had tried. But post separately the original code from getView() where you called the task. About 10 lines before and after the call will do i think.

Comment: the code is updated. i try to implement the decode Task but in this line i get error: DecodeTask dt2 = new DecodeTask(getContext(), imageView, ImagesID[position]); specially ImagesID[position]. i don't have this Integer anymore in my adapter.

Comment: Of course you have it. You put it in your Article class like you did with Name and Number. In the old you had .setText(Name[position]);  and .setText(Number[position]); You changed that to .setText(n.getName() and .setText(n.getNumber());  Now you have .setImageResource(n.getImgID()); and before you had DecodeTask dt2 = new DecodeTask(getContext(), imageView, ImagesID[position]); See the similarities?  I think now you will succeed...

Comment: i tried but there is something wrong, the pictures changes in the ImageView very fast. Some ImageViews still keep empty. the code is updated.

Comment: When you used your old adapter (without class Article) did you have the same problem?

Comment: No, then it's working on my phone. But by my colleague the app crashes after a while. Because of the AsyncTask problem.

Comment: Remove the statement after           holder = (ArticleHolder) v.getTag(); Can you clarify the asynctask problem?

Comment: no, after this the app crash with "NullPointerException"...

Comment: In which statement? You can find that in the logcat.

Comment: at getView: holder.textViewArtikel.setText(n.getName());

Comment: Something else. You said that your images are 10 to 20k. That is big. In this way you run out of memory soon. Which resolution do they have? I think 100x100 is enough to display in a listview item.

Comment: Well what is null? You have several possibilities here. holder, holder.textViewArtikel, n.

Comment: i'm use the pictures also for dialog(where i show the pictures bigger) resolution is 540x400 jpg

Comment: see the complete error from logcat above. how do you mean: holder, holder.textViewArtikel, n. ?

Comment: But then you should really resize it in decodeBitmapFromResource(int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight); You are not using the width and heigt to resize it to for instance 100x100. If you do it here then less memory is used.

Comment: One of the three is null. You can check each. if ( holder==null){} if holder.textViewArtikel==null{} if ( n==null ){}

Answer (score 0):

As I found your problem interesting I made an activity with your code.
The biggest problem I faced was where to get about 250 images. I first wanted to
ask you but than managed to resize 306 pictures to 100x100 and put
them in the drawable folder. Here is the changed getView().

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ArticleHolder holder = new ArticleHolder();

    final Article n = articleList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sergej_lazy_res_listitem, null);

        holder.textViewArtikel       = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.textViewArtikel);
        holder.textViewArtikelNummer = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.textViewArtikelNummer);
        holder.imageViewArtikel      = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewArtikel);

        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {

        holder = (ArticleHolder) v.getTag();
        DecodeTask dt1 = (DecodeTask)holder.imageViewArtikel.getTag( );
        if(dt1 != null)
          dt1.cancel(true);
      }


    holder.textViewArtikel.setText(n.getName());
    holder.textViewArtikelNummer.setText(n.getNumber());

    holder.imageViewArtikel.setImageBitmap(null);
    DecodeTask dt2 = new DecodeTask(getContext(), holder.imageViewArtikel, n.getImgID(), position ); 
    holder.imageViewArtikel.setTag(dt2);
    dt2.execute();

    return v;
}
```

As images of 100x100 were used there is no need to resize them.
Here the changed AsyncTask:

```
public class DecodeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
Context mContext;
ImageView v;
int resId;
Bitmap bitmap = null;    
int position;

public DecodeTask(Context context, ImageView iv, int res_id, int _position ) { 
    mContext = context;
    v = iv;
    resId = res_id;
    position = _position;
    v.setTag( this); 
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), resId);

  return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

 if( position < ListViewLayout.getFirstVisiblePosition() || position > ListViewLayout.getLastVisiblePosition())
     return;

 if ( v.getTag() == this )
    v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

 }
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine! what do you think, should i resize the images in AsyncTask?